# error reading from nslcd: Connection reset by peer

Tags: centos, pam, ldap, nss

I have a CentOS 7 machine that output the following to the /var/log/secure after every machine restart. I have to manually stop and restart the nslcd service to make these errors go away.

```
error reading from nslcd: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears the **nslcd** has lot of problems on various Linux builds / flavors. I switched to **sssd** and this issue is now resolved for me.

Comment: Maybe provide some details on how you solved it?

Comment: @JamesSumners, disable nslcd, enable sssd, and use that.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the cause of my issue with nslcd was some typos in the configuration.

Comment: @SaqibAli Did you mean "now resolved" instead of "not resolved"?

Comment: this answer doesn't make sense. nslcd is full supported so there might be an true explanation for this message. Moreover you doesn't have any sources for this information.